# Cannot import Tensorflow correctly when running a python code

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow

Help!!! I have been working on this for several days and am at wit's end!  I have been trying to run a python code that keeps giving me this error no matter what I do....

[Tensorflow problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmVus.jpg)

Comment: Which directory are you executing your program in?

Comment: I have my Python code and pertinent data files located on my Windows 10 desktop.

Comment: No. I meant which directory you typed in the `python` command in your command prompt.

Comment: I am executing it in my Desktop directory.

Comment: Then see the answer down below. I belive he is right.

Answer (score 0):

Your Numpy is older than expected. You can try to update numpy.

I suggest to use the anaconda distribution and install the official tensorflow package and should work seamlessly.